# How to shorten the time where MQTT broker checks for the connection state of a client

Tags: mqtt, emq

I am currently using [EMQ](http://emqtt.io/) as our MQTT broker. I need to get the latest "online" or simply the connection state of a client as quick as possible. Currently, I let my backend run a single client which subscribes to a $SYS topic, where the connection and disconnection event of a client will be published to as a message. When a client is connected, a connected message will be published to $SYS/.../connected. When it is disconnected, a disconnected message will be published to $SYS/.../disconnected.

The problem with this approach is that the disconnected messages will only be published immediately when the client is  disconnected normally. Like, when the client closes the connection by itself intentionally. But if the disconnection is due to unreachable network or power source cut-off, then the message will be published after 3 or more minutes.

I also tried using the LWT (Last Will Testament) approach but the result is similar as the one above. So I guess that if the disconnection happens unintentionally, the client won't have a chance to tell the broker that it will disconnect itself with the broker. So, it will definitely take sometime for the broker to notice that the client is actually disconnected.

So, my question would be, how would I shorten that time? I once suspect that the "keep-alive" thing has something to do with this matter. But after a couple of experiences, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep Alive is what you want

The important bit is to remember that brokers normally consider a client disconnected after about 1.5 times the keep alive value, not just the keep alive time. If you set the keep alive value small enough you should get notified pretty quickly after a client falls off line, but this will increase network traffic if the client isn't also publishing/subscribing to topics that have a message rate higher than the keep alive interval.

Full details of the Keep Alive in the MQTT spec can be found [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc385349237)

Comment: My keep alive was 60s. How come the message came after 3 minutes is you said the time it will take for the broker to notice the disconnection is about 1.5 times the value of keep alive. I was testing this locally with only 2 clients.

Comment: How are you disconnecting the client? It could be an artefact of EMQ but it works as expected with mosquitto

Comment: I just turned off the Wi-Fi. Then after waiting for about 3 minutes, the disconnection messages was published.

Comment: Hi, I went back to this problem and tested carefully this time. Then I noticed that the broker considers a disconnection 3 times the keep alive value. Thanks for the answer. You were right, I just didn't notice before that you said 1.5 times is "normally".